# How to set all attributes of ember object to null ?

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

I have an ember object 'Person' . For example ,

```
        person = { 
                  name: "Rahul" , 
                  age: "29", 
                  companyDetails: { tel: "9809823897" , name: "Amazon"},
                  phone: "2377373893" 
        }
```

How do i set all properties of this 'person' to null? I want the result to be

```
        person = { 
                  name: null , 
                  age: null, 
                  companyDetails: { tel: null , name: null},
                  phone: null 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 feature object spreading, the easiest way

Like this:

```
const newPerson = { ...person, name: null, age: null, phone: null }
```

Comment: I'm in need of a function which will set all attributes to null instead of setting everything to null by hardcoding.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6 or above, the answer by Hrimiuc should work; however a more old school way is this:

```
var obj = {
    prop1: "S",
    prop2: {
        subProp1: "h"
    }
}

var setAllToNull = function( objName ) {

    var keys = Object.keys( objName );
    for( var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++ ) {
        var currentKey = keys[ i ];
        if( Object.prototype.toString.call( objName[ currentKey ] ) === '[object Object]' ) {
            setAllToNull( objName[ currentKey ] ); 
        } else {
            if( objName.hasOwnProperty( currentKey ) ) { 
                objName[ currentKey ] = null; }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

I gave this just to explain the theoretical way you'd want to do it! :)